# Facebook graph API with batch request

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

facebook graph API batch request returns error, sample code is below:

> {\"error\":{\"message\":\"Invalid
>   parameter\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"error_subcode\":1487930,\"is_transient\":false,\"error_user_title\":\"Promoted
>   Object Is Missing\",\"error_user_msg\":\"You must select an object to
>   promote that is related to your objective, for example a Page post,
>   website URL, or app. Please add a promoted object and try
>   again.\",\"fbtrace_id\":\"GrLuBDDVrhZ\"}}

```
import requests
import urllib

ad_group_obj = 'name=fb_1200_628_04.png,object_story_spec={"page_id":"your 
page id","link_data":{"link":"https://www.link.com/"}}'
ad_group_obj = (urllib.parse.quote(ad_group_obj))
#print (ad_group_obj)
files = {
'access_token': (None, 'your access token'),
'asyncbatch': (None,'
[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"act_126671081468820/adcreatives","name 
":"My Async Ad Creative","body":"'+(ad_group_obj)+'",}]'),
}
print (files)

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/', files=files)
print (response.text)
```

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: No. facebook developer support team told to use marketing api batch request. if you find any answer please share with me. thanks.